# Tailwind css does not break long words

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this code:

```
<div id="toast-default" class="flex items-center p-4 w-full max-w-xs text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800" role="alert">
    <div class="inline-flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center w-8 h-8 text-blue-500 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-blue-800 dark:text-blue-200">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.395 2.553a1 1 0 00-1.45-.385c-.345.23-.614.558-.822.88-.214.33-.403.713-.57 1.116-.334.804-.614 1.768-.84 2.734a31.365 31.365 0 00-.613 3.58 2.64 2.64 0 01-.945-1.067c-.328-.68-.398-1.534-.398-2.654A1 1 0 005.05 6.05 6.981 6.981 0 003 11a7 7 0 1011.95-4.95c-.592-.591-.98-.985-1.348-1.467-.363-.476-.724-1.063-1.207-2.03zM12.12 15.12A3 3 0 017 13s.879.5 2.5.5c0-1 .5-4 1.25-4.5.5 1 .786 1.293 1.371 1.879A2.99 2.99 0 0113 13a2.99 2.99 0 01-.879 2.121z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        <span class="sr-only">Fire icon</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-normal break-words">Set yourself freesdfjhskdhfkhsdfhkshdfkjhksdfksjdfhkjshdkf.</div>
    <button type="button" class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-dismiss-target="#toast-default" aria-label="Close">
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

This text: `Set yourself freesdfjhskdhfkhsdfhkshdfkjhksdfksjdfhkjshdkf.` overflow the width of the component.

 For solving this i used: `break-words` class that should solve my issue but it anyway does not work. 
Question: How to break the overflow text in my case? What class should i use? 
DEMO: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rBM8GxwwVo

Comment: Maybe use `break-all` ?  Edit: oh this is concerning tailwindcss. Give me a sec.  Edit-edit: Yeah, `break-all` should do the trick: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break#break-all

Comment: @KayAngevare, if i use this `<div class="ml-3 text-sm font-normal break-all">Set yourself loremmas asda s testword .</div>` you can see that `testword` is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 4):

You should also set `overflow-hidden` to prevent the `div` from getting wider than it's parent.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/pYP5d3B4q4

Comment: could you help with this https://play.tailwindcss.com/4DHGzFdT4X . The issue is with the button, it goes away on the right place

Comment: also, when i remove it it shows that the right side looks without any padding.

Comment: I just deleted unnecessary elements https://play.tailwindcss.com/sSdOBlhJWO

Comment: Just saw, that the wrapper was also overflowing. Added also `overflow-hidden`. 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/rYoQhwFVl6

Answer (score 1):

Add width to the element. Also don't forget to work with the *[grid-based widths](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)*

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="toast-default" class="flex items-center p-4 w-full max-w-xs text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800" role="alert">
    <div class="inline-flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center w-8 h-8 text-blue-500 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-blue-800 dark:text-blue-200">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.395 2.553a1 1 0 00-1.45-.385c-.345.23-.614.558-.822.88-.214.33-.403.713-.57 1.116-.334.804-.614 1.768-.84 2.734a31.365 31.365 0 00-.613 3.58 2.64 2.64 0 01-.945-1.067c-.328-.68-.398-1.534-.398-2.654A1 1 0 005.05 6.05 6.981 6.981 0 003 11a7 7 0 1011.95-4.95c-.592-.591-.98-.985-1.348-1.467-.363-.476-.724-1.063-1.207-2.03zM12.12 15.12A3 3 0 017 13s.879.5 2.5.5c0-1 .5-4 1.25-4.5.5 1 .786 1.293 1.371 1.879A2.99 2.99 0 0113 13a2.99 2.99 0 01-.879 2.121z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        <span class="sr-only">Fire icon</span>
    </div>
    <!-- ADD WIDTH TO THE ELEMENT -->
    <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-normal w-9/12 break-words">
    Set yourself freesdfjhskdhfkhsdfhkshdfkjhksdfksjdfhkjshdkf.</div>
    <button type="button" class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-dismiss-target="#toast-default" aria-label="Close">
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I keep wondering why anyone would prefer overflooding HTML with a thousand classes instead of just writing a few lines of CSS? What is the benefit of using these systems?

Comment: @KayAngevare Using tailwind will increase your speed. There are some classes in tailwind e.g. `scrollbar-hidden` which will save you from writing 5 lines of code to support all browsers. If you don't like giving classes, you can instead use `@apply` in scss.

Comment: So tools like tailwind are kind of treshold front-end developing assistants, for people who prefer to use classes instead of writing .scss?

Comment: @KayAngevare exactly. like for exampl instead of `width: 8px` you just add the class `w-2`